# htaccess rule for redirection of any particular name to particular page

Tags: .htaccess

I am using PHP and I need to use a name say "Pranav dave" in url which should redirect me to "myprofile.php" what should i do?.. also the url should display me "Pranav dave".. and what should be the htaccess rule to redirect any html file to php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myprofile.php?profile=$1 [NC]
```

After that, you can use your urls like this `http://example.com/Pranav dave`. The only problem is, that the browser will rewrite the url, and after that, its looking like followink one `http://example.com/Pranav%20dave`

Comment: And what about redirecting any html file to php?

Comment: I'm not sure what you thinking about, but if you have an html file that you want to redirect, you can use for eg. javascript (`window.location = "target.php";`). But there are many ways to solve this problem. Another example with mod_rewrite: tell apache to handle html files, like php files (like this: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`) and so on.